# How to show alert-view and actions according to the response from the url in iphone SDKs?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I have a login section, which user can login with their username and password. There is a create account option available in the app.

When the username and password is validates successfully the url returns a array of the user-details and if the validation is unsuccessful there is an error code(error 404).

I got the correct response from the url but my need is that, when the alert-view with or responce with error code 404 comes it should not navigate to the main page.

How would I set a condition for that. My code is

```
 NSString *uname = _txtmemberId.text;

            NSString *pwd   = _txtpassword.text;

            NSString *urlVal = @"http:example&var1=";

            NSString *urlVal1 = [urlVal stringByAppendingString:uname];

            NSString *urlVal2 = [urlVal1 stringByAppendingString:@"&var2="];

            NSString *urlVal3 = [urlVal2 stringByAppendingString:pwd];



            NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                                           NULL,
                                                                                           (CFStringRef)urlVal3,
                                                                                           NULL,
                                                                                           (CFStringRef)@"\n" "",

                                                                                           kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );


            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];

            NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

            UIAlertView *loginalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" Message" message:resultString delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [loginalert show];

           [loginalert release];

            ParallelReadViewController *detailViewController = [[ParallelReadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParallelReadViewController" bundle:nil];

             //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
             // ...
             // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

             [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

             [detailViewController release];
```

if the login unsucessfull it will not navigate to the Parallelviewcontroller page.Resultstring is the string that i got from the url weather sucessful or unsucessfull.
How to do this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Declare resultString globally.Implement UIAlertView delegate method

```
       - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
if(resultstring == 404)
{
    status = YES;   // declare globally
}
    }
```

Put a check condition to push the view

```
if(status)
{
ParallelReadViewController *detailViewController = [[ParallelReadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParallelReadViewController" bundle:nil];

             //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
             // ...
             // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

             [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

             [detailViewController release];

}
```

Hope this work for u .

Comment: haii,thanks for the re[ly,then i didnt understand the code u mention above.i had a string called resultstring and i want to check that result string that if the resultstring is error 404 it wont able to redirect to the main page.result string is  json url

Comment: I have updated the answer. Create a constant with the error message and compare that constant with result string. I hope now its clear.

Comment: Both resultString and status has to be declared globally.

Comment: i tried a load,but nothing happens.my resultstring is {"status":"400"} when incorrect pasword or username enters.its a json stuff.any idea?thanks

Comment: compare like this (status == "400") as it is a string ur value of string should match hard code value.

Answer (score 0):

1 way>
you can get the html file with this code in a string so u can fetch the error from that with prsing  ..and then you can check the error message and navigate your page.

```
 NSString *str = @"YOUR LINK";
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error; 
    NSData *urlData = nil;
    urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",serverOutput);
    [request release];
```

2 way>
you can tell your webservice developer that give responce on the un successful login so with that reponse you can easily give condition with the help of if condition.